# LINQ's 'Convert to foreach' refactoring option for C# is missing in my Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, visual-studio-2017, refactoring

As the title says, the 'Convert to foreach' refactoring option for C# is missing in my Visual Studio 2017 (Professional edition).

I would like to know how do I enable/recover it. Maybe I'm missing to activate some option in Visual Studio settings or to install some missing component with the VS installer?.

The '[Refactoring to convert LINQ to a foreach statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/convert-linq-to-foreach?view=vs-2017)' article shows how this refactor option works:

[image]

However, when I select the next LINQ query in my code, I only see the "Extract method" refactor option...

```
IEnumerable<int> test = from int x in new[] { 1, 2, 3 } select x;
```

Comment: Which C# version are you using? Local functions are available starting from C# 7.0 version. So such refactoring will be enabled in C# code starting from v7.0

Comment: Using VS2017 doesn't guarantee that you are using C# 7.0 in your project.

Comment: @Hamlet Hakobyan Sorry I have not much experience when developing projects with C#. I investigated a bit to figure out why you said it does not guarantee it, now I know what you mean, VS allows to select the specific C# version to use. So, I selected v7.3, rebuilt the project, opened and closed again Visual Studio, but I still don't see the "convert to foreach" option.

Comment: It is very ugly implementation of refactoring. Try to select the LINQ query without the trailing semicolon.

Comment: You have to select the query part **only**: `from (...)` to `(...) grade`, **excluding the trailing semicolon**. If you include any other part, it won't trigger.

Comment: Thank you all, that was the problem I was including the semicolon in the selection.